# If an infinite series converges to a rational number, then does the series of terms divided by factorial always converge to an irrational number?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, rationality-testing

I was playing around with infinite series, specifically those that converged to rational numbers, and noticed (at least for the ones that I tried) that when I divided them by a factorial, they would become irrational.

My conjecture is if $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to a rational number, then $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!}$ always converges to an irrational number, with $j$ being a non-negative integer and $a_n$ being some sequence. I do know that it always converges, due to the comparison test, as the series with $a_n$ converges. However, I don't know if my conjecture is true or not.

Some series that I have tested are (I actually couldn't think of many rational-converging series):

1. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n} = \frac{x}{x-1}$ (for $|x| > 1$)
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\pi n)^2} = \frac{1}{6}$
3. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} = \frac{x}{x+1}$ (for $|x| > 1$)
4. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e \cdot n!} = 1$

When dividing them by $n!$, they all become irrational:

1. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n n!} = \sqrt[x]{e}$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\pi n)^2} \approx 0.11616$ (some hypergeometric monstrosity)
3. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[x]{e}}$
4. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e \cdot (n!)^2} \approx 0.83861$ (something to do with the modified Bessel function)

I have absolutely no idea on how to prove this, and I haven't found out very many series to test it on yet. How would I go about proving it, or do you know of some counterexamples?

One thing to note: series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e \cdot n!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n n! \sqrt{e}}$ are not valid counterexamples, because without the $n!$, they either don't converge or converge to an irrational number.

Another note: an example where $a_n = 0$ for all $n \geq$ some large $N$ is a trivial solution, so perhaps we shouldn't consider it. Perhaps $a_n$ could be restricted where there cannot exist some $N \geq j$ where $a_n = 0$ for $n \geq N$.

Comment: When $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge$ some large $N$, then...

Comment: Fix everything arbitrarily (subject to convergence) except $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then the two sums are of the form $a_1 + a_2 + x$ and $a_1 + a_2/2 + y$. By solving a linear system you can make the two sums whatever you want.

Comment: @SeanEberhard But I don't think that would necessarily disprove the conjecture above. If $a_1 + a_2$ is rational, then $x$ must be rational as well by the condition that the first series is rational. Also $a_1 + \frac{a_2}{2}$ would be rational. However, that doesn't show that $y$ is rational or irrational. Similarly for $a_1 + a_2$ being irrational. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying?

Comment: Set say $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = 1/2^n$ for all $n \ge 3$. Then $x = \sum_{n \ge 3} a_n$ and $y = \sum_{n \ge 3} a_n/n!$ are determined. Now we can find $a_1, a_2$ such that $a_1+a_2+x = a_1 + a_2/2 + y = 0$ by solving a linear system, namely $a_2 = 2y-2x$ and $a_1 = x - 2y$.

Comment: If you want to insist that all $a_i$ are positive and rational, that can be arranged too, but it's a little more technical -- let me know if you want the gory details.

Comment: More concretely based on your example 1 and @Sean Eberhard's comment: Let $a_n = 1/2^n$, with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ rational and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} = \sqrt e$. Form another sequence: $$\left(b_n\right)_{n=0}^\infty = \left(a_0, -2\sqrt e, 2\sqrt e, a_3, a_4, a_5,\ldots\right)$$ Then both $\sum b_n$ and $\sum \frac{b_n}{n!}$ are rational (but not exactly zero in this example).